# How to find out which method Mathematica selected?

Tags: options, implementation-details

There are commands like `NonlinearModelFit[]` or `NDSolve[]` that have the option `Method` it typically defaults to `Automatic`. How can you check after the evaluation of the command which method Mathematica picked?

Comment: Some functions have their defaults indicated in the manual. As an example, for solving (systems of) ODEs with `NDSolve[]`, by default it switches between `"BDF"` and `"Adams"`, depending on whether the system being solved is stiff or not. If you're performing nonlinear least squares with `FindFit[]`, *Mathematica* is smart enough to automatically use `"LevenbergMarquardt"`.

Comment: Of course, that is what Mathematics does. But how do I check? I can use `Options` to check which ones were given. But there is no such thing like `Method[%]` that informs me what Mathematics did. If I publish results I cannot write "The fitting was probably done with LevenbergMarquardt, but I can’t tell for sure, because there is no command to check."

Comment: [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) mentions some of the defaults taken.

Comment: "If I publish results I cannot write..." - ergo, you should try to specify options explicitly if you want everything to be transparent.

Comment: @uli: +1 It's an interesting question and I'm not sure that you'll find a satisfactory answer. I guess if you want to publish the results you can either specify the Mma version number you used, or manually choose the method that you use.

Comment: Still I’d would like to know Mathematica’s choice. Especially if it deviates from the default. ODEs are not my field of expertise, but is it decidable whether a system is stiff or not? Perhaps behind the various `Automatic`-options there are only heuristics, that may give a wrong classification?

Comment: "...is it decidable whether a system is stiff or not?" - it's not entirely foolproof, but *Mathematica* does have stiffness detection methods. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html) and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html) for instance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you can actually see (most of) what Mathematica is doing by using `Trace[..., TraceInternal -> True]`.

For example,

```
Select[Flatten[
  Trace[NDSolve[y'[x] == x && y[0] == 0, y, {x, 0, 6}], 
   TraceInternal -> True]], ! FreeQ[#, Method | NDSolve`MethodData] &]
```

shows the DE was evaluated using `` NDSolve`LSODA `` and Newton's method. (I think)

And

```
Select[Flatten[
  Trace[NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + x[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == 1/2}, 
    x, {t, 0, 10 Pi}, SolveDelayed -> True], 
   TraceInternal -> True]], ! FreeQ[#, Method | NDSolve`MethodData] &]
```

used `` NDSolve`IDA ``.

---

As an aside, here's something I just learnt from [Trott's Mathematica guidebook for numerics](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=xW5__5ga2IsC&lpg=PA416&ots=C3NjVWaJEx&pg=PA416), to see all of the methods and suboptions for `NDSolve`

```
{#, First /@ #2} & @@@ 
 Select[{#, Options[#]} & /@ (ToExpression /@ 
   DeleteCases[Names["NDSolve`*"],(* PDE method only *) "NDSolve`MethodOfLines"]), 
   (Last[#] =!= {}) &]
```

Comment: I just saw [ruebenko's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149/34). Using `TraceInternal` as above seems to give the same list of methods as his `data`, but it requires a lot of digging...

Comment: You can also use the second argument of `Trace`; for example, ``Trace[NDSolve[..], _NDSolve`InitializeMethod | _[NDSolve`MethodData[___]], TraceInternal -> True]``

Comment: @Simon, to check which method was chosen by `NSolve` instead of `NDSolve`, I changed `! FreeQ[#, Method | NDSolve`MethodData] &` to `! FreeQ[#, Method | NSolve`MethodData] &`, but it seems not to work, could you give some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

For `NDSolve` with **one step** methods you can use the `MethodMonitor`.

```
data = Last[
   Reap[sol = 
      NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30},
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
       "MethodMonitor" :> (Sow[NDSolve`Self[[0]]];)];]];
```

See:

[tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html)
[tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation.html)

Adams, BDF, IDA are multi-step methods and do not work with this approach.

Comment: Nice! But if I am not mistaken, this seems to be a `NDSolve[]` only solution?

Comment: @Uli , sorry only got this question now, yes, this is NDSolve specific.

Answer (score 12):

I asked this question once after a  presentation by Jon McLoone. His answer was that that was not possible and that Mathematica can switch methods many times if the situation asks for it. So it wouldn't be useful either. I agree that this is not completely satisfactory.