# What method does NDSolve use for solving PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, implementation-details, reference-request

What is `NDSolve`'s mode of operation? 
I use it to solve partial differential equations and never gave it too much thought. Recently, I came across [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected) question. Accordingly, I used  `Trace[...]` and realized that my 4th order, non linear partial differential equation was solved using an `LSODA` method.

Further digging revealed that `LSODA` [is a method](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/uscd1227) for ORDINARY DIFF EQS which chooses between `Adams` and `BDF` methods to solve the problem.

So... how in the first place did `NDSolve` convert my **PDE** to an **ODE**?

Any references would be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE

Comment: I think "mode of operation" is not very standard terminology.  I didn't understand what you were talking about before reading the question.  I edited the title, please review it.

Comment: @Szabolcs the new title works!

Comment: Just as a quick comment, MATHEMATICA uses the `LSODA` method by default if the `method`of solution option in `NDSolve[..]` is set to `Automatic`, and I don't just mean for stiff equations. Please do leave a comment with your thoughts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** The answer below is for Mathematica 9 or earlier.  Since version 10, Finite Element Methods are included:

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html

---

The methods `NDSolve` uses are documented in detail here:

- [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html)

[This section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html) says that PDEs are solved using the "method of lines", and explains which kinds of problems this method can deal with.  There's also a detailed example of how the method works.

> The numerical method of lines is a technique for solving partial
>   differential equations by discretizing in all but one dimension, and
>   then integrating the semi-discrete problem as a system of ODEs or
>   DAEs.
>
> ...
>
> It is necessary that the PDE problem be well posed as an initial value
>   (Cauchy) problem in at least one dimension, since the ODE and DAE
>   integrators used are initial value problem solvers. This rules out
>   purely elliptic equations such as Laplace's equation, but leaves a
>   large class of evolution equations that can be solved quite
>   efficiently.

Comment: I think you should mention that since version 10 there is also the "Finite Element" method, which can solve equations which were not possible to solve with "Methods Of Lines" (as e.g. the mentioned Laplace eq.). Among other things, the finite element method can also be used as an alternative to the methods of lines to discretize the space-like dimensions and create a system of ODEs to solve in time...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @Szabolcs, is it possible for us to solve 4th order C1 Problem in Mathematica, If yes, which example can we find??