# Determining the default Method used in optimization and root-finding algorithms

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, options

Is it possible to extract the `Method` which is used in functions like `NMinimize`, `FindRoot`, `FindMinimium`, and partners when one doesn't set this option explicitly? Basic example:

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]
```

What is used as `Method` here?

I expected to find some setting in `SystemOptions[]` but was unable to. Obviously `AbsoluteOptions[expr]` cannot be used in such a case since unlike a e.g. graphic, the minimization result does not contain this option information anymore.

Here is what is stated in the documentation of `Method`:

> With the default setting `Method -> Automatic`, *Mathematica* will automatically try to pick the best method for a particular computation.

This tells us the chosen `Method` depends on the input problem. Therefore, a fixed setting in `SystemOptions` wouldn't make sense.

Additionally, there exists a document describing [some internal implementations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#10453). Basically, you can extract most information from there, but I was hoping for a way to extract the used `Method` during a run.

Comment: For `NMinimize[]` (from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#10453)): "For linear cases, `NMinimize` and `NMaximize` use the same methods as `LinearProgramming`. For nonlinear cases, they use Nelder-Mead methods, supplemented by differential evolution, especially when integer variables are present."

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I know this document, but I thought there is a way to extract this information in a specific run. Let me add this to my question.

Comment: did you ask this question because its number 4000 :-)

Comment: @chris No, not on purpose but it's a nice coincidence.

Comment: This doesn't work, but how come `OptionValue` doesn't  get evaluated when/where the option exist?

`f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 16)^2;
first = True;
{sol, {{ mthd}}} = Reap[
   NMinimize[f[x, y], {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}},  
    Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", 
    EvaluationMonitor :> 
     If[first, Sow[OptionValue[Method]]; first = False;]]];
mthd`

Comment: For `NMinimize`, yes, it is possible. I described how to get diagnostic output [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize/4708#4708). For your example it seems to be that differential evolution is used.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Damn, I knew this post of yours but didn't remember. Would you mind to copy the basic information from there as answer?

Comment: Another possibility: ``Cases[Trace[NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x], Optimization`NMinimizeDump`method, TraceInternal -> True], {HoldForm[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`method], m_ /; FreeQ[m, Automatic]} :> m, Infinity]``

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize/4708#4708), we can obtain diagnostic output from `NMinimize` using an internal variable,

```
NMinimize; (* Auto-load package, in case we haven't called NMinimize already *)
Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$DiagnosticLevel = 3;
```

where the `3` means, as mentioned previously, that we would like to receive information at an intermediate level of detail. In fact, this also happens to be the lowest setting that states explicitly which method was used.

Trying your example minimization, we get output showing that differential evolution was used in this case:

[image: NMinimize diagnostic output]

Since this method only gives you a printout rather than something you can make use of programmatically, and because this internal option is of course completely undocumented anyway, in practice I'd probably tend to prefer J. M.'s suggestion of just grabbing the value of `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`method `` directly.

Comment: @J.M. Hmm, it's really hard to decide who get the accept since both answers are valid and solve the problem (initially, I was only interested in the method used by `NMinimize`!). I give the accept to Olek, since (I think) he did all the digging inside *Mathematica*-code.

Comment: @hal, no worries; he needs the rep more than me... ;)

Comment: FWIW, the variable ``Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$DiagnosticLevel`` seems to have been superseded by the function ``Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dbPrint``.  It seems to be called thus: ``Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dbPrint[level, stuff]``, where `stuff` seems to be a list of stuff.  The level that shows the method is `2`.

Answer (score 7):

At halirutan's behest: here's one way to reckon out the method used internally by `NMinimize[]` and cohorts:

```
Cases[Trace[NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x], Optimization`NMinimizeDump`method,
            TraceInternal -> True],
      {HoldForm[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`method], m_ /; FreeQ[m, Automatic]} :> m,
      Infinity]
```

where in this case, the output is `{HoldForm["DifferentialEvolution"]}`. Trying the same tactic on `NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]` yields `{HoldForm["NelderMead"]}`.

SFAICT, this only works since the guts of `NMinimize[]`/`NMaximize[]` are mostly written in high-level *Mathematica*; I'm not sure if the internals used can be teased out of `FindMinimum[]` or `FindRoot[]` in this manner.

([Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145) is a related question.)

Comment: `FindMinimum` is quite obscure ...

Comment: Well, that was not implemented in top-level *Mathematica* code, so yes, not transparent at all.