# When using NMinimize[...,Method->"DifferentialEvolution"] is an "iteration" different than a "step"?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, monitoring

Hopefully this question has a simple answer. I have the following bit of code:

```
fits = Quiet[
Check[
NMinimize[
{ssd, And @@ cons}, vars, 
AccuracyGoal -> accur, 
PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1.0, "CrossProbability" -> 0.0}, 
MaxIterations -> maxIter, 
StepMonitor :> (fitStep++)
], {}
]
];
```

where the variables *accur* and *maxIter* are set elsewhere. I've noticed that *fitStep* sometimes exceeds *maxIter* during the minimization, which seems to indicate that an "iteration" and a "step" are not the same thing in this context. If they're different, is there a way to monitor the "iteration" and not the "step"? I just want to be able to limit the fit to a certain number of iterations (to prevent it from going on too long) and monitor the progress against that limit.

EDIT: 16 May 2013

Alright I've put together a self-contained chunk of code to demonstrate the `MaxIterations` issue. I know it's not the most basic example but it's sure to reproduce what I'm seeing. The chunk of code below is commented, but just to summarize: I have some spectral data that I'm trying to fit with a sum of Logistic Power Peak functions using the Differential Evolution method. The important variables here are `vars`, `cons`, `args`, and `ssd`, as those are the arguments fed to `NMinimize[]`. The `ssd` variable contains a very large expression so evaluate it with caution.

Evaluate the following expression first in a separate cell to watch the progress of the minimization.

```
(* Watch the progress here. *)

Dynamic["Iterating: " <> ToString[fitStep] <> " / " <> ToString[maxIter] <> " ..."]
```

Change `maxIter` and the `"PostProcess"` option inside `NMinimize[]` (bottom) to see the various behaviors.

```
(* Set the number of iterations. *)

maxIter = 500;

(* Here's some data I'm trying to fit. *)

pts={
    {525,  3.95}, {527,  5.07}, {529,  5.15}, {531,  5.58}, {533,  5.85},
    {535,  6.53}, {537,  7.01}, {539,  6.79}, {541,  7.01}, {543,  7.43},
    {545,  7.18}, {547,  6.92}, {549,  6.34}, {551,  7.21}, {553,  7.75},
    {555,  7.65}, {557,  8.71}, {559,  8.89}, {561,  9.02}, {563,  9.72},
    {565,  9.62}, {567,  9.88}, {569, 10.50}, {571,  9.65}, {573,  9.71},
    {575,  8.52}, {577,  7.70}, {579,  8.15}, {581,  8.29}, {583, 10.00},
    {585, 10.00}, {587,  9.28}, {589, 10.80}, {591, 11.90}, {593, 13.80},
    {595, 14.90}, {597, 14.30}, {599, 15.30}, {601, 16.20}, {603, 16.30},
    {605, 17.90}, {607, 17.70}, {609, 19.20}, {611, 20.40}, {613, 20.80},
    {615, 21.40}, {617, 20.30}, {619, 18.40}, {621, 19.80}, {623, 19.90},
    {625, 20.70}, {627, 19.80}, {629, 18.60}, {631, 19.40}, {633, 20.40},
    {635, 20.50}, {637, 23.10}, {639, 22.50}, {641, 25.20}, {643, 26.40},
    {645, 26.10}, {647, 25.60}, {649, 25.20}, {651, 23.30}, {653, 23.10},
    {655, 23.00}, {657, 24.00}, {659, 22.70}, {661, 22.00}, {663, 21.70},
    {665, 21.30}, {667, 19.60}, {669, 20.30}, {671, 17.60}, {673, 18.20},
    {675, 17.40}, {677, 16.10}, {679, 15.60}, {681, 14.10}, {683, 12.20},
    {685, 12.10}, {687, 13.50}, {689, 13.90}, {691, 12.50}, {693, 12.00},
    {695, 11.60}, {697, 11.10}, {699,  9.41}, {701,  8.56}, {703,  6.69},
    {705,  6.50}, {707,  7.20}, {709,  7.03}, {711,  6.75}, {713,  6.01},
    {715,  6.97}, {717,  7.54}, {719,  7.76}, {721,  7.47}, {723,  7.33},
    {725,  6.93}, {727,  6.64}, {729,  6.25}, {731,  4.93}, {733,  4.67},
    {735,  4.06}, {737,  4.17}, {739,  4.90}, {741,  4.64}, {743,  4.63},
    {745,  5.11}, {747,  4.75}, {749,  4.45}
    };

(* This is the Logistic Power Peak (LPP) function. *)
(* I'm fitting with a sum of these (the sum is handled below). *)
(* #1 = a = height *)
(* #2 = b = center *)
(* #3 = c = width *)
(* #4 = d = asymmetry *)
(* #5 = s = reflection *)

LPP = (#2/#5)(#5+1)^((#5+1)/#5)
    * (1+Exp[(#6(#1-#3)+#4*Log[#5])/#4])^(-((#5+1)/#5))Exp[(#6(#1-#3)+#4*Log[#5])/#4]&;

(* These are just labels for each of the five peaks being fitted. *)

pkIndx = {121101022, 121111022, 121121022, 121131022, 121141022, 121151022};

(* For each of the five peaks, set initial values for the parameters a, b, c, d, and s. *)
(* #1 = a = height *)
(* #2 = b = center *)
(* #3 = c = width *)
(* #4 = d = asymmetry *)
(* #5 = s = reflection *)

MapThread[(a[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {4.26, 6.41, 3.68, 11.70, 3.87, 15.38}}];
MapThread[(b[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {534.67, 559.62, 583.72, 607.08, 629.76, 651.83}}];
MapThread[(c[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {5.02, 5.49, 5.96, 6.43, 6.91, 7.39}}];
MapThread[(d[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {5.94, 6.16, 6.38, 6.59, 6.79, 6.98}}];
MapThread[(s[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}];

(* Set lower constraints for each peak parameter. *)

MapThread[(daMins[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {3, 5, 2, 5, 0, 5}}];
MapThread[(dbMins[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}}];
MapThread[(dcMins[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}];
MapThread[(ddMins[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}];

(* Set upper constrainsts for each peak parameter. *)

MapThread[(daPlus[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}}];
MapThread[(dbPlus[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}}];
MapThread[(dcPlus[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}];
MapThread[(ddPlus[#1] = #2) &, {pkIndx, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}];

(* In my larger program, this checks to see which peak parameters are being fitted. *)
(* Here we're fitting all but s, which always takes the value 1. *)

bool = {
(daPlus[#] != 0 || daMins[#] != 0),
(dbPlus[#] != 0 || dbMins[#] != 0),
(dcPlus[#] != 0 || dcMins[#] != 0),
(ddPlus[#] != 0 || ddMins[#] != 0)
} & /@ pkIndx;

aPos = Flatten[Position[bool[[All, 1]], True]];
bPos = Flatten[Position[bool[[All, 2]], True]];
cPos = Flatten[Position[bool[[All, 3]], True]];
dPos = Flatten[Position[bool[[All, 4]], True]];

(* Make a table of variables for NMinimize[]. *)

vars = Join[
a0[#] & /@ pkIndx[[aPos]],
b0[#] & /@ pkIndx[[bPos]],
c0[#] & /@ pkIndx[[cPos]],
d0[#] & /@ pkIndx[[dPos]]
];

(* Make a table of constraints for NMinimize[]. *)

cons = Join[
(a[#] - daMins[#] < a0[#] < a[#] + daPlus[#]) & /@ pkIndx[[aPos]],
(b[#] - dbMins[#] < b0[#] < b[#] + dbPlus[#]) & /@ pkIndx[[bPos]],
(c[#] - dcMins[#] < c0[#] < c[#] + dcPlus[#]) & /@ pkIndx[[cPos]],
(d[#] - ddMins[#] < d0[#] < d[#] + ddPlus[#]) & /@ pkIndx[[dPos]]
];

(*
Make a table of arguments to be fed to the LLP[] function in the Sum below.
Normally this table contains numerical values for the parameters that aren't being fitted    
and variables for the ones that are.
Here we're fitting everything except s so the table contains only variables.
*)

args = MapThread[
{
aDum -> #2[[1]] /. {True -> a0[#1], False -> a[#1]},
bDum -> #2[[2]] /. {True -> b0[#1], False -> b[#1]},
cDum -> #2[[3]] /. {True -> c0[#1], False -> c[#1]},
dDum -> #2[[4]] /. {True -> d0[#1], False -> d[#1]}
} &,
{pkIndx, bool}
];

(*
Create the sum of squared deviations for NMinimize[] to minimize.
The inner Sum[] sums over the 5 LLP[] functions at a given x, and each LLP[] gets its     
arguments from the "args" table.
The outer Sum[] sums the squared deviations over all the data points.
*)

ssd = Sum[
(
Sum[
LPP[pts[[i, 1]], aDum, bDum, cDum, dDum, s[pkIndx[[j]]]] /. args[[j]],
{j, Length[pkIndx]}
]
- pts[[i, 2]]
)^2,
{i, 1, Length[pts], 1}
];

(* Run the fit. *)

fitStep = 0;

fits = NMinimize[{ssd, And @@ cons}, vars,
AccuracyGoal -> 3,
PrecisionGoal -> Infinity,
Method -> {
"DifferentialEvolution", 
"ScalingFactor" -> 1.0, 
"CrossProbability" -> 0.0, 
"PostProcess" -> False
},
MaxIterations -> maxIter,
StepMonitor :> (fitStep++)
];
```

My observations:

- with `"PostProcess->False"`:

  - `MaxIterations` =  300 ---> # iterations = 220
  - `MaxIterations` =  500 ---> # iterations = 250
  - `MaxIterations` = 1000 ---> # iterations = 500
  - `MaxIterations` = 1200 ---> # iterations = 600
- with `"PostProcess->FindMinimum"`

  - `MaxIterations` =  300 ---> # iterations = 221
  - `MaxIterations` =  500 ---> # iterations = 251
  - `MaxIterations` = 1000 ---> # iterations = 501
- with `"PostProcess->True"`

  - `MaxIterations` =  300 ---> # iterations = 286
  - `MaxIterations` =  500 ---> # iterations = 316
  - `MaxIterations` = 1000 ---> # iterations = 566
  - `MaxIterations` = 1500 ---> # iterations = 816

Lastly, I did find a comment in *The Mathematica Guidebook for Numerics* by Michael Trott claiming that (paraphrasing) in `FindMinimum[]`, `MaxIterations` determines the *effective* number of evaluations in *each* search direction. I believe it was on page 371 but I'll have to double-check.

Comment: Can't you `Sow` them and find out? (I don't know a lot about how this works, so I could be wrong). In any case, please include a minimal example (i.e., definitions for ssd, cons, vars, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about Sow-ing the iteration number. As far as I know, only StepMonitor and EvaluationMonitor allow access to information about the progress of the optimization. In this case I think EvaluationMonitor doesn't apply (I may be wrong) and I'm already using StepMonitor to keep track of the "step". I guess I'm actually claiming that they *are* different because I set the MaxIteration and I'm seeing that the output of the StepMonitor exceeds MaxIteration.

Comment: Also, not sure that the definitions of _sad_, _cons_, and _vars_ matter for this question. They're not simple definitions, but in short _ssd_ is the "sum of squared deviations" that I'm minimizing, _cons_ is a set of "Anded" constraints, and _vars_ is the set of variables that I'm fitting.

Comment: It's best to post a working self-contained example.

Comment: ^ I'll see what I can do about posting an example. I'm going to have to dissect my code a little (this excerpt is part of a much larger program).

Comment: @Adam That's why I asked for a _minimal example_, not your actual problem. It could just be the simplest "Hello world" of `NMinimize` that is sufficient to illustrate your problem. Regardless of whether it matters or not, it makes life simple for everyone who might answer your question if they can simply copy your code and run it to test it. Most of us don't have the time or inclination to get creative and think up of a valid function to minimize, appropriate conditions, etc — all of this _before_ we actually get to the heart of your problem.

Comment: ^ Understood. I just thought it might be as simple as the definition of "iteration" vs. "step". I'll put together a basic example.

Comment: An indicator that they're different: `f[x_?NumericQ] := Sin[.4 x] + .7 Cos[.6 x] x;
{steps, eval} = 
  First /@ Last@
    Reap[NMinimize[{f@x, -10 < x < 10}, {x}, 
      Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", 
      StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, f@x}, "steps"], 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f@x}, "eval"]], {"steps", "eval"}]; Plot[f@x, {x, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Point[eval]}, {Green, Point[steps]}}]` Also look at the lengths of `steps` and `eval`.

Comment: Regarding differential evolution itself: there is no conceptual distinction between a "step" and an "iteration" since this algorithm does not perform line searches or similar. As for what `NMinimize` thinks of as a step or an iteration, that's a different matter, especially for constrained optimizations where barrier parameters or penalty functions may need to be adjusted in between DE iterations to guide the process into the correct minimum. For more, see my answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4708) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14709).

Comment: I've figured it out, I think: "iterations" seems to be the sum of `NMinimize` steps and `FindMinimum` postprocessing steps. If you want to disable the postprocessing (not recommended, since `FindMinimum` converges very quickly), use `Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "PostProcess" -> False}`. Interestingly, `"PostProcess" -> {FindMinimum, MaxIterations -> #}` has no effect on the actual number of postprocessing iterations, while `"PostProcess" -> {KKT, MaxIterations -> #}` does. I guess `FindMinimum` is not so easily dissuaded from its mission.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using `"ScalingFactor" -> 1.0, "CrossProbability" -> 0.0` deliberately so that the optimization never converges? This may influence how `NMinimize` behaves if after a certain number of iterations it continues to see no improvement. Anyway, I would repeat my previous suggestion to try this again with diagnostics switched on: this way, `NMinimize` will tell you explicitly what it is doing. If you specify `MaxIterations` much larger than needed for convergence, some may well be used to adjust barrier parameters, etc.; for small `MaxIterations`, the limit is obeyed.

Comment: @Oleksandr: Yes, the settings are deliberate. I browsed publications, tutorials, etc. a little when I was selecting values for the ScalingFactor and CrossProbability and what I gathered (which may be totally wrong) is that low values of the CP lead to searches that are slow and robust, while larger values yield fewer improved solutions, but the improvements can be big. I chose to go with slow and robust. For the SF, 1 is supposed to allow greater mobility in the solution space.

Anyway, I'll take a look at the diagnostics and report back what I find; thanks very much for the suggestion!

Comment: @Oleksandr: Also, if the optimization weren't converging with an accuracy of 3 wouldn't MMA generate a message?

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether you already took this into consideration, but it's important to note that *Mathematica*'s `CrossProbability` is reversed relative to the literature--traditionally 1 retains the mutant vector while 0 keeps the target, but here it's the other way around. That is, a value of 0 (*Mathematica*'s 1) yields a one-dimensional hill climbing approach, assuming that *Mathematica* implements DE as described by Storn and Price rather than using this as a literal probability. (I did look at the code at one point, but I've now forgotten what it does.) ...

Comment: ... Good general settings are something like $F \approx 0.5-0.9$, $CR \approx 0.1, 0.9$, so your values are a bit extreme, but if it works for you, fine. As for the lack of message: `NMinimize` won't produce one if the global optimization doesn't converge but the later postprocessing does; both must fail for an error to be returned to the user. I suppose this is because global optimization algorithms like DE provide no useful error estimate, whereas local methods do, and thus the message is only really meaningful in the latter case.

Comment: Oleksandr, thanks for those pointers. I had not noticed the difference in the CP definitions. So far I've been able to get my fits to converge using _F_ = 1.0, _CR_ = 0.0, but they take quite a long time (several minutes for ~5 peaks). I'll try adjusting the values a bit and see if it doesn't improve performance. Much appreciated.