# Overriding AccuracyGoal in NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I override the AccuracyGoal parameter in NMinimize? Instead of the evaluation stopping at the required Accuracy, I want it to stop after a specific number of iterations, even if the AccuracyGoal is not reached.
I tried the following **example code**, but it doesn't stop after 100 iterations.

```
NMaximize[{Norm[Array[c1, 10], Infinity]+Norm[Array[d1, 10], Infinity], 
   And @@ Table[-1 <= c1[i] <= 1, {i, 1,10}] && And @@ Table[-1 <= d1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, 10}]}, 
  Flatten[{Array[c1, 10], Array[d1, 10]}],Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing",MaxIterations -> 100];
```

This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25210/when-using-nminimize-method-differentialevolution-is-an-iteration-diff) is similar to my query, but is yet to be answered.

Comment: There is a typo in `Table[-1 <= d1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, d10}]` , change `d10` to `10` and your code runs.!

Comment: Yes, the code runs, but it doesn't stop after 100 iterations.

Comment: That means NMaxmize doesn't need 100 iterations to find the solution!

Comment: Yes for this particular toy example. But for a much more complex problem, I would like to stop the evaluation after say N iterations.

Comment: `NMaximize[{Norm[Array[c1, 10], Infinity] + 
   Norm[Array[d1, 10], Infinity], 
  And @@ Table[-1 <= c1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, 10}] && 
   And @@ Table[-1 <= d1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, 10}]}, 
 Flatten[{Array[c1, 10], Array[d1, 10]}], 
 Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", MaxIterations -> 10]` performs a warning "NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 10 iterations" and

Comment: ``{2., {c1[1] -> -0.350629, c1[2] -> 0.887276, c1[3] -> 0.354475, 
  c1[4] -> -0.337351, c1[5] -> 0.108962, c1[6] -> -0.835742, 
  c1[7] -> -0.5555, c1[8] -> -0.571501, c1[9] -> -1., 
  c1[10] -> 0.384825, d1[1] -> 0.1141, d1[2] -> -0.439006, 
  d1[3] -> 0.505844, d1[4] -> -0.986217, d1[5] -> -0.313406, 
  d1[6] -> -0.37064, d1[7] -> 0.0101464, d1[8] -> 1., 
  d1[9] -> 0.885465, d1[10] -> -0.13678}}``

Comment: Yes exactly. That means AccuracyGoal is overriding the MaxIteration option, I would like this not to happen.

Comment: Adding `AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5` options to the above code, you obtain `{2., {c1[1] -> -0.350629, c1[2] -> 0.887276, c1[3] -> 0.354475, 
  c1[4] -> -0.337351, c1[5] -> 0.108962, c1[6] -> -0.835742, 
  c1[7] -> -0.5555, c1[8] -> -0.571501, c1[9] -> -1., 
  c1[10] -> 0.384825, d1[1] -> 0.1141, d1[2] -> -0.439006, 
  d1[3] -> 0.505844, d1[4] -> -0.986217, d1[5] -> -0.313406, 
  d1[6] -> -0.37064, d1[7] -> 0.0101464, d1[8] -> 1., 
  d1[9] -> 0.885465, d1[10] -> -0.13678}}` without any messages.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. But with this, the precision with which calculations are being done internally(i.e., in the case of simulated annealing, guesses are being made or probability of accept-reject is being calculated) decreases. These won't matter much when we look at this toy example, but this will lead to unexpected issues for a much more complex objective function.

Comment: Also, if the AccuracyGoal mentioned is reached before the MaxIteration specified the code will stop without reaching the MaxIteration. And I want it to reach the specified number of Iterations.

Comment: First, I think ` AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5` gguarantee enough precision. Second, I don't understand the purpose of your demand "And I want it to reach the specified number of Iterations ". Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: So, I am testing an algorithm that uses this optimization using Simulated annealing as a sub-part. So, would like to evaluate my algorithm using different limits for the iterations allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't find your explanation to be serious.

Comment: I want to benchmark my algorithm for a particular optimization, and the benchmarking requires "accuracy vs no. of iterations used" data.