# Using StepMonitor/EvaluationMonitor with DifferentialEvolution in NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

My question about tracking the progress of a minimisation/fitting process is two-fold:

**1.** The first part of my question can be considered a slight duplicate/follow-up of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114796/step-monitor-option-in-differentialevolution). There the OP asked what exactly is passed to the `StepMonitor`-Option when using the "DifferentialEvolution"-method. The answer by Oleksandr R. states that only the fittest individual of each generation is passed. This is fine by me but when I try the following nothing is passed:

```
data = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12345]; 
Table[{x, Exp[-2.3 x/(11 + .4 x + x^2)] + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]},
    {x, RandomReal[{1, 15}, 20]}]];

nlm = Reap@NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a x/(b + c x)], {a, b, c}, x, 
    Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}}, 
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{a, b, c}]]
```

compare this to the same expression using `EvaluationMonitor` instead of `StepMonitor`.

**Question:** Is what is passed to/by `EvaluationMonitor` the fittest individual of the current generation (like Oleksandr R. suggested for `StepMonitor` which sadly seems not to be accurate any more)

**Question 2** Is there a straightforward way to pass the value of the fitness/cost-function of said best individual i.e. the squared differences between estimate and data?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`EvaluationMonitor` is going to be called whenever the objective function is being evaluated, that is much more often than `StepMonitor`.

The reason for not getting any points back is that the `StepMonitor` specification is not propagated to the `NMinimize` call. Try the following syntax instead

```
nlm = Reap @ NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a x/(b + c x)], {a, b, c}, x, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, StepMonitor :> Sow[{a, b, c}], 
     Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}]
```

For the values of the objective function at these points, one could build the sum of squared residuals by hand, but there is also an internal function that can be used (the added factor of two is because in the default 2-norm case the objective function is $\frac12 \bf r \cdot \bf r$, where $\bf r$ is the residual vector).

```
obj = Optimization`FindFit`ObjectiveFunction[data, Exp[a x/(b + c x)], {a, b, c}, x];
nlm = Reap @ NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a x/(b + c x)], {a, b, c}, x, 
  Method -> {NMinimize, StepMonitor :> Sow[2 obj[{a, b, c}]], 
    Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for uncovering ``Optimization`FindFit`ObjectiveFunction``, it is indeed a very convenient way to create a [`NumericalFunction`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513)! There is also ``Optimization`FindFit`ResidualFunction``.

Comment: @ilian For the given example the sum of the squared residuals equals 1.2583 (see e.g.  `ANOVATable`). This is exactly double of the last value coming out of ``Optimization`FindFit`ObjectiveFunction``.

Comment: @demm Yes, the objective function being minimized is actually $\frac12 \bf r \cdot \bf r$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: A mathematical note, for the uninitiated: the reason for the factor of $\frac12$ is that it makes for tidy expressions for the corresponding gradient and Hessian.

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you use? I tried using the internal `ObjectiveFunction` but it does not work. Evaluating for instance `obj[{1,2,3}]` yields some unevaluated expression containing `Experimental``NumericalFunction` I tried `Needs["Optimization`"]` which results in an `noopen`-error

Comment: @Sascha Sorry, I made a typo when adding the 2. Should work in Mathematica 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

One could also estimate the sum-of-squared residuals (or any other diagnostic, statistical property etc.) directly within Sow

```
  Reap@NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a x/(b + c x)], {a, b, c}, x, 
      Method -> {NMinimize,StepMonitor :> 
         Sow[Sum[(data[[i,2]]-Exp[a data[[i,1]]/(b+c data[[i,1]])])^2,
{i,1,Length[data]}]],Method->{"DifferentialEvolution"}}]
```