# NMinimize and Minimize give different solutions for approximate inputs?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

According to the [Minimize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) documentation, when provided with approximate inputs, `Minimize` invokes `NMinimize`.  However, different specifications of the same domain give different results when `NMinimize` is invoked explicitly versus implicitly via `Minimize`.

For example, defining a random input sample:

```
A = {{0.4277047469835642`, 
    0.16878397349541197`}, {0.6416571036236569`, 0.5910551264554926`}};
B = {{0.9699948146542698`, 
    0.8036723082029285`}, {0.02882838531248111`, 0.9544230849675173`}};
b = {0.29803837933767596`, 0.6635349216438007`};

Minimize[
 {Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
  x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0},
 x \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]

(* {0.727324, {x -> {0.0802987, 0.50132}}} *)
```

But calling `NMinimize` explicitly gives a higher value:

```
NMinimize[
 {Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
  x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0},
 x \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
(* {0.746419, {x -> {0.185227, 0.441771}}} *)
```

Interestingly, other forms of specifying the domain for NMinimize seem to give the global minimum:

```
NMinimize[
 {Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
  x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0},
 x \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals]]
(* {0.727324, {x -> {0.0802988, 0.50132}}} *)
```

FWIW, all of this is in 12.0.0 for Mac OS X

Any thoughts?  I'm mostly curious how the different domain specifications are changing the numerical optimization procedure.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) it look like `Minimize` does not run `NMinimize` in this case.

---

By default `NMinimize` will use the same methods as [`LinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html) and for vector minimization it will give completely unreliable result (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#10453)).

This can be seen by running:

```
NMinimize;

Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$DiagnosticLevel = 3;

NMinimize[{Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
   x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0}, x ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
(* {0.925839, {x -> {0.692173, 0.291364}}} *)
```

Because of no debug output (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14709/2342)), it doesn't use any minimization methods.

You can try to use different methods:

```
NMinimize[{Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
   x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0}, x ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Method -> "Automatic"]
(* {0.735908, {x -> {0.127568, 0.474466}}} *)

NMinimize[{Norm[A.x - b, Infinity] + Norm[B.x - b, Infinity],
   x \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0}, x ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Method -> "NelderMead"]
(* {0.727324, {x -> {0.0802987, 0.50132}}} *)
```

You can get the list of available methods with:

```
Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$Methods
(* {"Automatic", "DifferentialEvolution", "MeshSearch", \
"NelderMead", "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch", \
"NonlinearInteriorPoint"} *)
```