# Intermediate variables in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm interested in using NDSolve as an integrator for a system of differential equations that looks like the following:

```
x'[t] == f[x[t], p[t]]
p'[t] == g[x[t], p[t]]
```

Both f and g are expensive functions to compute, but they both need to perform similar computations, so it is cheaper to write

```
vec'[t] == newf[vec[t]]
```

where vec is a list whose elements are `{x,p}`. Now, I have a quantity computed in newf that just depends on x and p at a given time (call it y), and I would like this quantity to be included in the solution. I could compute it separately as

```
vec'[t] == newf[vec[t]]
y[t] == calcy[vec[t]]
```

but this would be expensive, as I'd be computing it twice. I'd like to include it in the vector and just include it with newf's output, but as I'm specifying y and not y', this doesn't work. I tried making a list out of everything as

```
{vec'[t], y[t]} == newf2[vec[t]]
```

but *Mathematica* spits back

> NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {vec[t], y[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

Any suggestions?

Here is a minimal working example, where I would like to have y return in the solution as well as the vector solution.

```
f[vec_List] := Module[{y},
  y = Norm[vec];
  {1, y}]

NDSolve[{vec'[t] == f[vec[t]], vec[0] == {0, 0}},
  {vec},
  {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[vec[t] /. %, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I would first try to see how it works when nexf2 is linear

Comment: I tried it with `{vec'[t],y[t]}=={{0,0},0}`, which is as simple as it gets, and received the same error message.

Comment: `{vec'[t],y[t]}=={{0,0},0}` is not a correct syntax. The correct syntax, with initial condition, is `NDSolve[{vec'[t] == {0, 0} , y[t] == 0, vec[0] == {0, 0}}, {vec, 
  y}, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Sure, I know this, but it doesn't help with the my question - how to specify the driving term `vec'[t]` and the auxiliary function `y[t]` in the same function.

Comment: I don't understand very well the motivation behind making the same function. I think this is not possible, or if it is possible, it doesn't bring anything interessing. You say "computing `newf[]` and `calcy []`" would be "twice computing". Do you mean that newf and caly are similar function ?

Comment: ! I'm just discovering that you have added a minimal working example !

Answer (score 1):

**Very specific to the example in the question, you can do :**

```
NDSolve[{vec'[t] == {1, y[t]}, y[t] == Norm[vec[t]], 
  vec[0] == {0, 0}}, {vec, y}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

**Here is another solution that corresponds better to what you describe in your comments:**

```
f01[vec_List] := Module[{y}, y = Norm[Take[vec, 2]]; {1, y^2, y}];

NDSolve[{
  vec'[t] == driving[t],
  driving[t] == f01[vec[t]],
  vec[0] == {0, 0, 0},
  driving[0] == {1, 0, 0}
  },
 {vec, driving}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

encountered difficulties :

- NDSolve understand that `driving` is of length 3 only after addition of `driving[0] == {1, 0, 0}`
  (which is accepted without error !)
- one can not modify the length of `vec` and `driving` in `vec'[t] == driving[t]`
  my solution (efficient ?) was to add a dummy element in `vec` so that Length[vec]=3
- on the contrary one can extract a part of `vec` in the function f01 (see
  `y = Norm[Take[vec, 2]]`)

Note :
With this code `NDSolve` gives a answer without complaining.
I have not verified that this answer is OK.

Hope this helps

Comment: The minimal working example was just that - a minimal example. What I'm actually wanting to do is to use a long and complicated module, where `y` is an intermediate result used in calculating `vec'[t]`. I'm trying to return `vec'[t]` as well as `y`. For the trivial example that I gave above, you can do what you suggest, but for the more complicated scenarios, it's not so simple. Although, I guess I could have all of the driving terms stored along with the solution in a similar manner...

Comment: I tried generalizing your suggestion to the following:  
`f[vec_List] := Module[{y}, y = Norm[vec]; {1, y^2, y}];`
`NDSolve[{vec'[t] == Drop[driving[t], -1], driving[t] == f[vec[t]], vec[0] == {0, 0}}, {vec, driving}, {t, 0, 1}]`.
However, this gives me an error of a different sort...

Comment: Ok, this is much closer to what I want. I found that as you say, you cannot use `Drop[driving[t],-1]` in the equation in NDSolve. What you can do, however, is to call a function `droplast[driving[t]]`, where `droplast[x_List]:=Drop[x,-1]`. I'm really not sure what the difference is, but it seems to work. The importance of this is that the integrator step size will then not be influenced by the dummy function (and it doesn't spend effort integrating the dummy function).

Comment: I have tried something of the kind of your `droplast`, but it didn't seem to work. Can you post the code in a comment, please ? (I will see that later)

Comment: `f01[vec_List] := Module[{y}, y = Norm[vec]; {1, y^2, y}];`
`g[vec_List] := Drop[vec, -1];`
`NDSolve[{vec'[t] == g[driving[t]], driving[t] == f01[vec[t]], vec[0] == {0, 0}, driving[0] == {1, 0, 0}}, {vec, driving}, {t, 0, 1}]` was what I was using. Perhaps the _List condition is important?

Comment: Sigh. I've discovered that using this trick of an intermediate variable causes NDSolve to use about four times more steps than it would otherwise. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: On my side, I have discovered that the trick has made NDSolve change the algorithm to the DAE solver (IDA), but I know a very few things on this subject.

Comment: To know what method NDSolve has used : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145/5467

Comment: I don't know if you can "unaccept" my answer. If you can, do it. I'm afraid that the subject is far from resolved, and the question was very good, despite the score.

Comment: @ruebenko Maybe we are missing something trivial in this post ?

Comment: I've come up with a different way of doing it. It's not particularly nice, but it goes something like the following:
`NDSolve[{vec'[t]=f[t], vec[0]={0,0}}, {t,0,1}, StepMonitor :> AppendTo[list, {t,variable}]]`
Here, f[t] is a function that sets an intermediate variable to a value that can then be recorded by the step monitor. So long as the list is initialized to `{{0,intermediate[0]}}` to begin with, it seems to work.