# NIntegrate, view integration options

Tags: numerical-integration

The *Mathematica* manual says:

`NIntegrate` symbolically **analyzes its input** to transform oscillatory and other integrands, subdivide piecewise functions, and **select optimal algorithms**.

1. How do I extract the specific value of `Method` (and other related options) being used for a particular case? In other words, if the method is set to `Automatic`, how do I know which method was **actually** used for integration for a given case?
2. Can I achieve better accuracy if I modify the parameters for `NIntegrate`? I mean, does the automatic selection work well for a majority of cases (if an integrand is non-problematic)? [from your experience]

Comment: _"There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy"_ ... http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html

Comment: believe me, i read this manual

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145/5

Comment: however, the solution mentioned doesn't work