# Algorithms behind implemented Mathematica functions

Tags: implementation-details

When I use Mathematica for analysis and I write a publication, readers often ask me: *"What is the algorithm behind your calculation?"*. I answer that I did it with Mathematica and if they are interested I give them the code.

**Is it possible to find out which algorithms are used for implemented Mathematica functions?**

That would be very helpful.

---

**Edit: 16th June 2015**

From Wolfram Research I got the answer to this question:

> "Currently, we do not disclose such information to the public"

Comment: If you could narrow down the functions a bit further that might be helpful.

Comment: When using the setting `Method -> Automatic`, *Mathematica* will often perform a number of heuristics and then select an algorithm it thinks is appropriate. If you need to be able to say "I used method so-and-so", you will have to provide an explicit setting.

Comment: (BTW, I'm pretty sure this is a dupe; I just can't find it.)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I thought the same, and equally couldn't find it!

Comment: Another thing to consider is that some functions use multiple algorithms and switch between them while fining a solution for a single run. So from some part of job a function uses one algorithm then a change in  the nature of the problem is detected and a function may switch to another solution method on the fly.

Comment: If you can clarify which functions you are referring too in particular, then this question could be edited and reopened.

Comment: Re: "Currently, we do not disclose such information to public", in my experience when I asked specific implementation questions, they usually sent useful references to the papers the methods are based on.

Comment: @J.M., blochwave [(145)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected) seems like the question you might have missed

Comment: That's it! Thanks @shrx!

Comment: In my opinion, the greatest flaw of Mathematica is that they don't give enough information about the algorithms used.

Answer (score 10):

Turning my comment into an answer, one option is to read through the Wolfram page titled ["Some Notes on Internal Implementation"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html), which gives some detail about the implementation of many functions.

It is definitely worth noting the introduction to that page though (my own emphasis):

> General issues about the internal implementation of the Wolfram
>   Language are discussed in "The Internals of the Wolfram System". Given
>   here are brief notes on particular features.
>
> **It should be emphasized that these notes give only a rough indication
>   of basic methods and algorithms used. The actual implementation
>   usually involves many substantial additional elements.**
>
> Thus, for example, the notes simply say that `DSolve` solves
>   second-order linear differential equations using the Kovacic
>   algorithm. But the internal code that achieves this is over 60 pages
>   long, includes a number of other algorithms, and involves a great many
>   subtleties.

Indeed, further down the page:

- `Integrate` uses about 500 pages of Wolfram Language code and 600 pages of C code.
- `DSolve` uses about 300 pages of Wolfram Language code and 200 pages of C code.

So there is a lot going on under the hood, and you might not always be able to answer your readers' questions fully.