# How could I know the Method adopted in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

In `NDSolve`, different methods may lead to different results. For my codes

```
Clear["Global`*"]
α = 110.; β = 55.; δ = 1.; μ1 = 18.; μ2 = 42.; μ = μ2/μ1;
ηb = 10.;deltap = .18;p0 = 0.03;T = 1.0;
f0 = T/(2 \[Pi]);n = 1; fn = n*f0;inipoint = 4.;tlength = 1000.;
w[λ_, ξ_] := (-((μ1*α)/2) Log[ 1 - (λ^(-4) + 2*λ^2 - 3)/α] 
           -(μ2*β)/2 Log[ 1 - (λ^-4*ξ^4 + 2 λ^2*ξ^-2 - 3)/β])/μ1
dw[μ_, ξ_] = D[w[λ, ξ], λ];
ξin[λ_, ξ_, x_] = (1 + (λ^3 - 1) (x^3 - 1)^-1 (ξ^3 - 1))^(1/3);
f[λ_, ξ_, x_] =  dw[λ, ξin[λ, ξ, x]]/(1 - λ^3);
sup[x_] := ((δ + x^3)/(1 + δ))^(1/3)
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
np = 11; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}];
intf[x0_, ξ0_] := 
 Block[{y = x0, ξ1 = ξ0}, 
  Do[points[[i]] = 
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, y, sup[y]][[i, 1]], {i, 1, np}];
  Do[weights[[i]] = 
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, y, sup[y]][[i, 2]], {i, 1, np}];
  int = Sum[(f[λ, ξ1, y] /. λ -> points[[i]])*
     weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]; int]
eq1 := x''[t] + (1/
          2 x'[t]^2 (3 - δ/
             x[t]^3 (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-4/3) - 
           3 (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + intf[x[t], ξ[t]] - 
        deltap - p0*Sin[2 \[Pi]*fn*t])/
      x[t]/(1 - (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) == 0;
eq2 := (3 ηb*(1 - (x[t]^-4*ξ[t]^4 + 2 x[t]^2*ξ[t]^-2 - 
           3)/β)) ξ'[t] == ξ[
     t]*(μ (x[t]^2*ξ[t]^-2 - x[t]^-4*ξ[t]^4));
t0 = TimeUsed[];
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, ξ[0] == p, x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == p}, {x[t], x'[t], ξ[t]}, {t, 0, tlength}, {p}(*,
   Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}*)];
p3 = pfun[inipoint];
TimeUsed[] - t0
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@p3[[1 ;; 2]], {t, 0.9*tlength, tlength}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{3, 8.}, All}, 
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^-1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]]
```

The result is
[image: fig1]

When `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"` is applied in `ParametricNDSolveValue`, the code is

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, ξ[0] == p, x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == p}, {x[t], x'[t], ξ[t]}, {t, 0, tlength}, {p}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
p3 = pfun[inipoint];
TimeUsed[] - t0
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@p3[[1 ;; 2]], {t, 0.9*tlength, tlength}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{3, 8.}, All}, 
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^-1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]]
```

the result is
[image: fig2]

We can find some defferences for the two diagrams when a specific method is applied in `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

And if the equations is written as one order differential equations as below

```
eq1 := x'[t] == y[t]
eq2 := y'[t] == -(1/2 x'[t]^2 (3 - δ/
            x[t]^3 (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-4/3) - 
          3 (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-1/3)) + intf[x[t], ξ[t]] - 
       deltap - p0*Sin[2 \[Pi]*fn*t])/
    x[t]/(1 - (1 + δ/x[t]^3)^(-1/3))
eq3 := ξ'[t] == ξ[t]*(μ (x[t]^2*ξ[t]^-2 - 
        x[t]^-4*ξ[t]^4))/(3 ηb*(1 - (x[t]^-4*ξ[t]^4 + 
           2 x[t]^2*ξ[t]^-2 - 3)/β))

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x[0] == inipoint, 
     y[0] == 0, ξ[0] == inipoint}}, {x[t], y[t], ξ[t]}, {t, 0,
     tlength}, {p}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
p3 = pfun[inipoint];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@p3[[1 ;; 2]], {t, 0.9*tlength, tlength}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{3, 8.}, All}, 
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^-1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]]
```

The result is
[image: fig3]

another different result is given.
Questions:
1. For the same equations, I just specify the `Method` or change the form of equations, why the results are different and which one is better?
2. Is it possible to know the specific method or strategy adopted in funtions like `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolveValue`?
Any ideas would be much appriciated!

Comment: Avoid numerical parameters if possible.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Numerical parameters are responsible for the error, and the method adopted in `NDSolve` also does that. Do you know some approaches to find out the default method options selected by MMA in `NDSolve`？

Comment: Haven't checked in detail, but it's probably [butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect). In short, there probably exists no way to obtain accurate enough result for large enough `tlength`.

Comment: @   keanhy14 If you (or NDSolve ) performs simplications before solving the ode's rounding effects may give "different" equations. That's why your solutions are different I think.

Comment: @xzczd Probably it is that, but the initial conditions is given in my example. Moreover, the default method options also puzzle me if I don't set it myself previously.

Comment: "…the initial conditions is given in my example." Not sure if I've understand your comment correctly, but do notice a system that's sensitive to initial conditions will also be sensitive to numeric error, and different methods will probably cause different numeric error. "Moreover, the default method options also puzzle me if I don't set it myself previously. " I fail to understand this part of the comment.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry about that! I mean the method to solve the differential equaions is RungeKutta or something else(since so many numerical methods exist )? and Is it possible to confirm it?

Comment: Check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145/1871

Comment: ``Trace[
 pfun[inipoint],
 Verbatim[NDSolve`InitializeMethod][meth_, __] :> meth,
 TraceInternal -> True]`` usually shows the method(s). (The first is often `Automatic`, followed by the actual one.)