# Mathematica internal source code for a numerical method

Tags: implementation-details, open-source

I read [this](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/11/30/six-reasons-why-the-wolfram-language-is-like-open-source/) (*Six Reasons Why the Wolfram Language Is (Like) Open Source*), which inspired me to re-investigate Mathematica's implementation of some numerical methods. I would like to see the code that evaluates, say, a differential equation via `NDSolve[___,Method->((Some Method))]`.

I've tried the approaches given in the blog post (i.e., `ResourceFunction["PrintDefinitions"][NDSolve]`), but this only gives me a list of available `NDSolve` options. Some searching around revealed [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we) beautiful package, `Spelunking`, but that seems to do more or less the same thing.

```
Spelunk[NDSolve]

{
 {{
   {Options[NDSolve] = {AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
      Compiled -> Automatic, DependentVariables -> Automatic, 
      DiscreteVariables -> {}, EvaluationMonitor -> None, 
      InitialSeeding -> {}, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic, 
      MaxStepFraction -> 1/10, MaxSteps -> Automatic, 
      MaxStepSize -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, 
      NormFunction -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
      StartingStepSize -> Automatic, StepMonitor -> None, 
      WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}}
  }}
}
```

I've also attempted defining functions that call `NDSolve` with a specific method, but that did not reveal anything useful. I also found other Q/A pairs that pointed to `Trace[]` and `TracePrint[]`, but those also didn't reveal anything substantive.

If Mathematica is (like) open source, how can I find the source for this example (or ones like it)?

**Update:** I found the option `Trace[NDSolve[{x'[t] == t, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 6}],  TraceInternal -> True]` that opens up a can of back-end worms. This might be the best we can do (h/t [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected?rq=1)).

Comment: The article states that the source code of functions written in C cannot be accessed.  My guess is that much of `NDSolve` is in C for efficiency, or that it calls functions from other libraries.  Very interesting question, though.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I read somewhere sometime ago that about 50% of Mathematica is written in C and C++ and the rest is in Mathematica (i.e. Wolfram Language).

Comment: @bbgodfrey I agree that lower-level `NDSolve` calls are surely in C/C++, but I'm also confident that there's more of a Wolfram Language backend to `NDSolve` than what appears here. I ran into the same situation with `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I feel I've gotten to know a fair amount about `NDSolve` from these tutorials:

- [NDSolvePlugIns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)
- [NDSolveDesign](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html)
- [NDSolveStateData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html)

You can also spelunk part of the code for various methods if you root around `` NDSolve`* ``:

```
?NDSolve`*Rung*a

?NDSolve`LSODA

?NDSolve`*inearly*

[etc.]
```

LSODA is based on LSODE which can be googled.  I've found Fortran and C implementations.  Obviously, LSODA would have to be rewritten for *Mathematica*, if for no other reason than to handle arbitrary working precision numbers.  Similarly for IDA, which is part of Sundials.

From the tutorials, you find out that most `NDSolve` methods are implemented in an object-oriented way. The constructor is usually spelunkable and has the form:

```
LSODA /: NDSolve`InitializeMethod[LSODA,....
```

or generally

```
id /: NDSolve`InitializeMethod[id,....
```

The object created has the form `id[data]` and the methods have the form `id[data][meth]` such as `id[data]["Step"[..args..]]` to advance integration one step.

FEM is a recent extension of `NDSolve` that is well documented and fairly spelunkable (root around `` NDSolve`FEM`* ``), though mesh generation is probably in C. It also relies on LAPACK, which can be googled.  See:

- [FEM User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html)

I have not yet figured out how to output my own dense output (`InterpolationOrder -> All`) using the `NDSolve` framework.  (`NDSolve` will do it for you, using its own algorithm, and I can do it by explicitly constructing an `InterpolatingFunction` directly. I cannot get `NDSolve` to use the data I compute to construct the IF, though.)

P.S. You can add `TraceInternal -> True` to `TraceScan` in
to [`traceView2[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29340#29340), if you want an organized display of the available internal steps.  Beware, you might have to kill Mathematica if the output is of the order of gigabytes.  I have had to do so.  So do it advisedly.  Limit the number of steps `NDSolve` can take, and don't do it on a huge PDE.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.